Can't link custom object in report type
I have an object Object__c that has lookups to opportunity and account. I'm trying to create a report type linking opportunity to Object__c to account, however after I've linked custom object to opportunity, there are no available objects to select for object C.
Also tried to select Object__c as primary object for report type and it still has no available objects to link.
FLS is fine on lookups and all objects are available for reporting so not sure what's going on.

When building a custom report type, you can't go "down" and then "up" again. Instead, you can start from Object__c, and then use the "Add fields via lookup" to include account and opportunity fields. Or, you can create a Joined Report using Account and Object__c on one side, and Opportunity and Object__c on the other side. As a third option, you can also start either Account and Object__c or Opportunity and Object__c, then use the "Add fields via lookup" feature to add the remaining fields you're looking for.
